# Dozer problems with maps generic types and proxies

Tags: java, hibernate, dictionary, proxy, dozer

In our company we have discovered that Dozer has problems with copying fields from a hibernate entity to a simple DTO (a simple POJO) with fields, that are maps of other entities.
This is how it looks:

```
class MyJPAEntity{
     @JPAMappings(FetchType.EAGER)
     Map<Integer, EmbeddableJPAEntity> map;
}

class MyDto{
    Map<Integer, MyOtherDto> map;
}
```

Soo, the Dozer, when trying to copy the fields from the Entity to DTO tries to somehow copy the proxy not its contents, thus raising LazyInitializationException (even though the Fetch Type is EAGER). We figured out, that we can create a wrapper, and a custom converter that deals with the situation:

```
public class MaybePersistentMapToHashMapConverter extends
    DozerConverter<Map, Map> implements MapperAware {

    public static class Wrapper {
        private Map map;

        public Wrapper() {
        }

        public Wrapper(Map map) {
            this.map = map;
        }

        public Map getMap() {
            return map;
        }

        public void setMap(Map map) {
            this.map = map;
        }
    }

    private Mapper mapper;

    public MaybePersistentMapToHashMapConverter() {
        super(Map.class, Map.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void setMapper(Mapper mapper) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    @Override
    public Map convertTo(Map source, Map destination) {
        return map(source, destination);
    }

    @Override
    public Map convertFrom(Map source, Map destination) {
        return map(source, destination);
    }

    private Map map(Map source, Map destination) {
        Wrapper wrapper;

        if (source instanceof PersistentMap) {
            wrapper = new Wrapper(new HashMap<>(source));
        } else {
            wrapper = new Wrapper(source);
        }

        if (destination == null) {
            Wrapper map = mapper.map(wrapper, Wrapper.class);
            return map.map;
        } else {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    }
}
```

So this stuff, just wraps the map so that the dozer does not copy the proxyMap. I just configure a mapping in code:

```
mapping(fromType, toType, oneWay())
            .fields("map", "map",  FieldsMappingOptions.customConverter(MaybePersistentMapToHashMapConverter.class)
```

So far so good. **So what is the problem?** The problem is with the other way mapping - from a DTO to the Entity. Instead of copying from a MyDto to MyJPAEntity entries into Entity (with mapping the inner DTO to inner Entity, It actually copies into the MyJPAEntity a map with entries - probably it cannot guess what is the target type, and instead of mapping objects, it just copies them.

So I was able to solve the problem as well, by specifying a hint for map types:

```
fields("map", "map", FieldsMappingOptions.hintA(MyOtherDto.class), FieldsMappingOptions.hintB(EmbeddableJPAEntity.class) )
```

I probably helped some people allready ;) And was happy that I solved my problems.

**UNTIL I had to copy values from an Entity to another Entity using doser**. Now, If I use hints, I get LazyInitException, if I use the wrapping converter from above the hints are ignored by the mapper. 
And the sourceforge docs for Dozer are inaccessible right now. 
Does anyone have an idea how to use the mapper and to force it to use my hints? Or how to properly configure it by mappings builder?

I would say that the used mapper in MaybePersistentMapToHashMapConverter actually is not aware that it should use the hints, as it is unaware that it is actually mapping a field of name "map"

Answer (score 2):

In our project we solved this problem and stuck badly in a problem exactly like your solved one ;).

your LazyInitializationException maybe is for calling .class in your map method for dozer.
that's because dozer will instantiate new Entity and fill it and this entity is not in current session.
we change our dozer map method calling from:

```
A_Entity newEntity = dozer.map(dto,A_Entity.class);
```

to:

```
A_Entity newEntity = new A_Entity();
dozer.map(A_dto,newEntity);
```

and in other way:

```
A_dto dto = dozer.map(entity,A_DTO.class);
```

to:

```
A_dto dto = Spring.context.getBean("a_dto");
dozer.map(entity,dto);
```

i hope this will usefull.